# SQL query to fetch values of parent to child

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, `ITEM` and `TARIF`. In tarif table I have price for parent item and some children. Now I have to fetch price of parent to its children by joining `TARIF` table to the `ITEM` table. In tarif table some parent will not be there, but when joining, it is creating a line for parent and child with "NULL" value. I don't want to export items if their parent does not exist in `TARIF` table.

`Item` table

```
status  item_code ga_article
-----------------------------
Parent1 1234      1234   X
child1  1234      1234 01 x
child2  1234      1234 02 x
parent2 2345      2345   X
child21 2345      2345 01 X
child22 2345      2345 02 x
parent3 3456      3456  X
child31 3456      3456 01 X
```

`tarif` table

```
item_code gf_article  price
----------------------------
1234      1234  X     100
2345      2345  X     150
2345      2345 01 X   200
```

NOW when I join `TARIF` to the `Item` table to get the price

```
select 
    ga_article,
    case 
       when t.price is null and i.ga_article like i.item_code +'X%' 
          then (select top(1) price from tarif 
                where GF_ARTICLE like item-code + '%' ) 
          else price
    end as amount
from 
    article
left join 
    TARIF on gf_article = ga_article
```

My output is :

```
ga_article  amount
-------------------
1234  X      100
1234 01 x    100
1234 02 x    100
2345  X      150
2345 01 x    200
2345 02 x    150
3456  X      null
3456 01 x    null
```

I don't want to see the last two line with null value

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN GF_PRIXUNITAIRE IS NULL
            AND ga_article LIKE ga_Codearticle + '%X' 
          THEN (SELECT TOP(1) GF_PRIXUNITAIRE FROM tarif 
                WHERE GF_ARTICLE LIKE ga_Codearticle + '%' 
                  AND GF_DEVISE='QAR' ) 
          ELSE GF_PRIXUNITAIRE
    END AS price
FROM  
    Article A 
LEFT JOIN 
    tarif L ON gf_article = GA_ARTICLE 
            AND GF_DEVISE = 'QAR' 
            AND GF_REGIMEPRIX = 'TTC' 
WHERE
    GA_STATUTART <> 'UNI' AND GA_CODEARTICLE <> ''
```

My expected output is:

```
ga_article  amount
---------------------
1234  X      100
1234 01 x    100
1234 02 x    100
2345  X      150
2345 01 x    200
2345 02 x    150
```

Comment: Maybe use `inner join` instead of `left join` ?

Comment: include one more condition in where clause - > where amount is not null

Comment: If i use Inner join , i was not able take parent price to child

Comment: Thank you Marc_s ,Sahi for answering me

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(select ga_article,
case when t.price is null and i.ga_article like i.item_code +'X%' then(SELECT TOP(1) price FROM tarif WHERE GF_ARTICLE like item-code+ '%' ) 
else price
end as amount
from article
left join TARIF on gf_article = ga_article ) AS A WHERE A.amount IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can end up your query as

```
from article a
join tarif t on t.item_code = a.item_code
```

So, use below as joining with an inner join by `item_code` columns

```
select ga_article,
       case
         when t.price is null and i.ga_article like i.item_code + 'X%' then
          (SELECT TOP(1) price
             FROM tarif
            WHERE GF_ARTICLE like item - code + '%')
         else
          price
       end as amount
  from article a
  join tarif t on t.item_code = a.item_code
```